# Multiple web config files in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Well, yes there are multiple posts on the same subject. One of the solutions for my problem is multiple web.config files but I am not sure if it works.

The problem:

I have a asp.net project. I have two clients (having their own storage and database) on which i need the application to be deployed. Storage and database are just two examples but there are many other settings unique to the client which can be managed in app settings. Whatever changes i do the project code, i need to deploy for both the clients.

Currently my web config looks like this:

```
<!-- GHR Settings -->

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="conn-string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<acntName>;AccountKey=<acntKey>" />
    <add key="StorageURL" value="<storageurl>" />
    <add key="ProfileURL" value="<ProfileURL>" />
    <add key="GenericURL" value="<GenericURL>" />
    <add key="IDocURL" value="<IDocURL>" />
    <add key="LogosURL" value="<LogosURL>" />
    <add key="DocsURL" value="<DocsURL>" />
    <add key="DefaultPassword" value="pass123" />
  </appSettings>

  <!-- TP Settings -->

  <!--

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="conn-string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<acntName>;AccountKey=<acntKey>" />
    <add key="StorageURL" value="<storageurl>" />
    <add key="ProfileURL" value="<ProfileURL>" />
    <add key="GenericURL" value="<GenericURL>" />
    <add key="IDocURL" value="<IDocURL>" />
    <add key="LogosURL" value="<LogosURL>" />
    <add key="DocsURL" value="<DocsURL>" />
    <add key="DefaultPassword" value="pass123" />
  </appSettings>

    <add key="DefaultPassword" value="pass123" />

  </appSettings> -->
```

As you can see, I have duplicated the settings and comment one client's settings, deploy on the server. Then I do it for other client.

This works alright, but too much maintenance during the publishing and prone to errors.

Please suggest what is the correct way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Configuration transforms, one configuration per client. Try searching for that.

Comment: create two webconfig and two publish profiles , exclude one web config from each..

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in my case is create a separate config file for the `DB connectionstring` and reference that file inside your web.config. By this way you can have the same web.config for both your clients and would only need to send the connectionstring.config file only once!

Inside your web.config

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConfigFiles\ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

And inside that file put the connectionstring

Same thing can be done for  section